# How to put a chart in grid

Tags: r

Is there a way to put a .png in a grid. I wanted to display 4 .png single charts in one, using grid.

[image]

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to show four PNG files (i.e. image files you already have on disk) on an R graphics device, or draw four plots on the one device and have that exported as a PNG?

Comment: Sorry, if am not clear in explaining.. I've 4 .png already on disk and I wanted to display.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said it's probably not a great idea, but

```
library(gridExtra)
library(png)

img <- rasterGrob(readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png")),
width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc"))


grid.arrange(img, img, img, img, ncol=2)
```

will display 2x2 png files on a device.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three ways to do this in base graphics.

1. Use `layout()` (which is my favourite):

   ```
   layout(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2))
   for(i in 1:4)
       plot(1:10)
   layout() # reset
   ```

   With `layout()` you pass in a matrix that contains integers which index the sub-plots that the device has been split into. How these indexes are arranged in the matrix controls the layout. The 2x2 layout is given by this matrix

   ```
   R> matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
        [,1] [,2]
   [1,]    1    3
   [2,]    2    4
   ```

   Note that fills by columns. To fill by rows, use `byrow = TRUE` in the `matrix()` call

   ```
   R> matrix(1:4, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
        [,1] [,2]
   [1,]    1    2
   [2,]    3    4
   ```

   A more complex layout that the 2x2 one can be achieved by creating the indexes in the matrix as you want the device to look. For example, for a device with 3 rows, with first row containing 1 plot region on right of the device, the second row with a single plot region covering the whole row and on the third row 2 plot regions, we would do this

   ```
   matrix(c(0,1,
            2,2,
            3,4), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
   ```

   Filling that with plots gives

   ```
   layout(matrix(c(0,1,
                   2,2,
                   3,4), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
   for(i in 1:4)
       plot(1:10)
   layout(1) # reset
   ```

   [image]

   Similar layouts can be achieved with `split.screen()`. See 3 below.
2. Use the `mfrow` or `mfcol` parameters. The former fills the device with plots by rows and the latter by columns

   ```
   op <- par(mfrow = c(2,2))
   for(i in 1:4)
       plot(1:10)
   par(op)  # reset
   ```
3. A third way is to use `split.screen()`

   ```
   split.screen(c(2,2))
   for(i in 1:4) {
       screen(i)
       plot(1:10)
   }
   close.screen(all = TRUE) # reset
   ```

   `split.screen()` can also take a matrix input, like `layout()`.

Depending on how many plot regions you split the device into, you may need or want to shrink margins of the plots. For that see `?par` and the various ways in which the margins can be defined (e.g. parameter `mar`).

To get these as a PNG file, wrap all commands in

```
png(file = "foo.png", .....) ## the ..... is where you place options, see ?png

## plotting commands here

dev.off()
```

e.g.

```
png("layout.png", height = 600, width = 600, pointsize = 14)
layout(matrix(c(0,1,
                2,2,
                3,4), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
for(i in 1:4)
    plot(1:10)
layout(1) # reset
dev.off()
```

[which is what I used to create the plot figure I showed above.]

Comment: this is fantastic, but if I have all the (e.g 4 plots) already created as an individual .png, is this the same method I can use to display?

Comment: No, and if the 4 plots (pngs) were generated in R, you'd be better off wrapping the code to generate the 4 plots in one of the options I show above. Rendering the PNG as rasters on a plot device is a recipe for poor quality.

Comment: oh thanks.. btw Just wanted to explain why I am doing this.. my client wants e.g all 4, Chart1.png, chart2.png...etc.. as seperate file and they wanted a combined .png which will have the same 4 charts in one .png file. The problem is its kinda re-running the same code for the charts, which drastically slows down the complete process. that's the reason I wanted to create a 4 .png which is already created and just use layout kinda of thing to display there by speed up the processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with ggplot, `facet_grid()` might be what you are looking for:

```
df <- data.frame( x = rnorm(40), y = rnorm(40) )
df <- cbind( df, expand.grid( c('A', 'B'), c('C', 'D' ) )  )
head( df )

            x          y Var1 Var2
1 -1.27990165  1.1697183    A    C
2 -0.65083905  0.4743215    B    C
3  0.23181562  0.5092162    A    D
4 -0.01370950 -0.1704988    B    D
5 -1.20182791 -0.3525845    A    C
6  0.04877524  0.8801793    B    C

library( "ggplot2" )
g <- ggplot( df ) +
  geom_point( aes(x = x, y = y) ) +
  facet_grid( Var1 ~ Var2 )
ggsave( "plot.png", g )
```

[image]